# Why does a popup modal dialog appear during PreExecute method execution?

Tags: ssis

Whenever I run a package a modal dialog without title, with the text "PreExecute()" and an Ok button appears and pauses the process until the ok button is clicked. I've tried to find the reason for this popup to appear, but I can't find anything in event handlers or anywhere else.

Any idea which can be the reason and how to avoid it?

Comment: The `preExecute()`-Method is part of a Script Component. So check your Script Components if you have a `MsgBox` somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having spent a lot of time trying to solve this mistery, the problem was with a custom SSIS component, created in Visual Studio.

There was, in fact, a `MessageBox("PreExecute()")` but it was out of the reach of SSIS. I have found it in the original source code of the custom component, removed it, and deployed the assembly again. An the problem has vanished, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

There may be two reasons.

1. IF you use the script transformation inside your dataflow task. You
   will find the methods called "PreExecute()" and "PostExecute()".
   There might be an Message box inside it. Please check that and
   comment that out if you don't want to see the message box.
2. In BIDS, you will see the "Event Handlers" tab. There might be any
   "Script task" in the "onPreExecute" event[for anyone of the
   component / at the package level] which has following snippet in the
   main method. Please comment that if you don't want to see the
   message box.

`MessageBox.Show("PreExecute()");`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help, but, unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem. I've checked all the EventHandlers of the offending task and all of its children task. An there's no script task.

Comment: If you're curious about this problem, I finally found it. See my own answer. Thanks for your help!